# How to automate parts of a big .NET application in Powershell?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, .net-assembly, read-eval-print-loop

My goal is to be able to call some application code from a powershell script.

For example, the application has the code necessary to do some work. I would like to call this code from the Powershell REPL.

The problem is that I cannot just load the application assemblies manually one by one in the Powershell REPL for the following reasons:

1. The application assemblies are not in GAC
2. I do not want to copy the application assemblies to C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
3. Loading the assemblies with the explicit file path is a pain - there are many of them, custom resolution seems to be required (`AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` or `AppDomain.TypeResolve` something like that - painful)

So, is there a way to do what I want?

One direction I was thinking about is create a new .NET application, which would reference the big application and the Powershell assemblies and would open a custom PowerShell REPL. This way it should have access both to Powershell and to my application assemblies natively.

The problem is that I do not know how to embed the Powershell REPL. Note, that I am not asking how to run a PowerShell script - I want the entire REPL, the interactive shell. Do not know though if it is possible - please advise.

Comment: if you did end up creating a new .NET application, you'd have to reference the assemblies of your larger app anyway, right? Wouldn't it be easier to copy the assemblies into a single folder and open them through Powershell, without trying to figure out how to create your own REPL for it?

Comment: The new application could be a project in the big application's solution. The references could be simple project references. But what do you suggest? Copying the app assemblies into the PowerShell system folder? Or create a copy of powershell system directory and run powershell.exe from there?

Comment: Please, motivate the closing vote.

Comment: [this article](http://www.sbrickey.com/Tech/Blog/Post/Manually_resolving_assembly_dependencies_in_PowerShell) explains what I guess you ran into, problems with dependencies when loading assemblies. I would simply copy the assemblies into some other directory (doesn't have to be the powershell dir) and load them by looping thru each file. You may be able to get this to work by the method you described (loading an assembly that itself references the others), I'm not sure.

Comment: Nope, loading an assembly that itself depends on other would not help if they do not belong to the bin folder of the exe, in this case powershell.exe

Comment: well, I guess as far as I know the answer to your question is no, there isn't a way to embed the powershell REPL into an application, so you'll either have to include all of your assemblies, or write it yourself. Maybe someone else will know a better way.

Comment: Of course there is a way to implement PS REPL in an application but it is difficult and not practical unless this is a designed part of this application. The whole UI of such REPL has to be implemented manually.

Comment: Obviously, this is not my intention. I was hoping the PowerShell creators has provided for such a scenario. Apparently I am wrong.